# Nginx setup between 2 servers

Tags: nginx

I have 2 servers,
The first one contains 2 websites (located in 2 separate directories):

1. https://example.com/site1
2. https://example.com/site2

The second server contains 1 website in root folder (React website).
Can you please help me to set up nginx on first server to make it point to the second server when user access to https://example.com.

Answer (score 2):

Since `nginx` would be running in `port 80`, thus you need to run your `web hosting content` onto another `port` for example port 3000 from your first server.

In your `nginx.config` file, you would need to create an `upstream` where you list the server that nginx needs to re-route to: (before making changes to the file, i would recommend that you make a copy of it)

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
 }

upstream server_banks {
  server localhost:3000; # if not localhost put the ip of the server
  server second_server_ip:portNumber;
}

server { # nginx service will operate on port 80
  listen 80; 
  server_name example.com 
 # it could your first server's ip or example.com if the domain is associated with that ip
   location / {
    proxy_pass http://server_banks;

   }

}
```

After you save the config, reload service && restart

Comment: Thank you! I will check this

Answer (score 2):

You need nginx running on both server2 and server2, then set nginx config as follow

*On Server 1*

```
#####server1####
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://second_server_ip:80;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        }
        location /site1 {
             alias /path/to_site1_dir/;
        }
      location /site2 {
             alias /path/to_site2_dir/;
        }
}
```

*On server 2*

```
###Server2#####

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /path/to_site_dir_for-server2;

        location / {

        }
}
```